# x86_64 Warning : character constant too long [-w+other] (nasm)

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, nasm, compiler-development

I am writing a compiler in attempt to switch my programming language from interpreted to compiled

this is the code my script generated:

```
section .bss
  digitSpace resb 100
  digitSpacePos resb 8
    string_at_index_0 resb 12
    string_at_index_0_len resb 4

section .data

section .text
    global _start
_start:
   mov rax, "Hello world"
   mov [string_at_index_0], rax
   mov byte [string_at_index_0_len], 13

   mov rax, 1
   mov rdi, 1
   mov rsi, string_at_index_0
   mov rdx, string_at_index_0_len
   syscall

   mov rax, 60
   mov rdi, 0
   syscall
```

when i run this code with `nasm -f elf64 -o test.o test.asm` i get this warning:

`warning:character constant too long [-w+other]`

can anyone help me with this , and also if anyone could suggest a better way to output a Hello world that would be helpful too!

Comment: `mov rax, "Hello world"` probably isn't valid. Declare the string literal in the .bss segment and load its address instead.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: It would be valid if it was 8 bytes or fewer; multi-byte character constants in NASM work the same as integer literal.  e.g. `"ab"` is `(0x61<<8) | 0x62`.  As is, it's just truncated with a warning.  If registers were 12 bytes wide, this code would work, since it is storing the string bytes to memory and passing a pointer to it to a `write` syscall.  Would also work to `push rax` / `mov rsi,rsp`.  Of course it's much simpler to just put string literals in static storage in the first place, not store them from immediates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mov rax, "Hello world"
```

RAX is an 64-bit (8 byte) register, you are trying to put 11 bytes into it.

If you want to store immediate data to memory, you can `mov rax, imm64` to put 8 bytes into RAX and then push it or store it.  Or you can `push "hi!"` as a 32-bit immediate if you want.

Here is a simple hello world:

As can be seen you don't want to put the message inside the register, you want to put a pointer to the message into rsi.  Since the message is constant, you might as well start with it in a data section instead of an immediate, so you don't have to run instructions at run-time to store it.

```
section .data                 ; or .rodata

msg: db "Hello World", 10     ; including a `\n` newline
.len equ $ - msg              ; assemble-time constant

; equivalent to
; msg.len equ 12        ; because the distance between here and the start of msg is 12 bytes.

section .text
    global _start
_start:

   mov rax, 1       ; write call number, __NR_write from asm/unistd_64.h
   mov edi, 1       ; to stdout
   mov rsi, msg     ; pointer to message
   mov rdx, msg.len ; length of the message that we defined earlier
   syscall          ; write(1, "Hello World\n", 12)

   mov  eax, 60         ; __NR_exit
   xor  edi, edi
   syscall              ; _exit(0)
```

Ideally, your compiler should place string literals in the `.rodata` section (read-only data) and pass pointers to them when using them in functions.

See also *[How to load address of function or label into register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57212012/how-to-load-address-of-function-or-label-into-register)* - `mov rsi, msg` is the least efficient way to do that, despite being the most "obviously" and simple.

Comment: That makes sense, how should i move the string inside the variable then?

Comment: You need to declare it as a variable and then use its address, I will give you an example when I can

Comment: @liveno added a simple hello world example

Comment: @liveno if you are familiar with C you can check this page to see the parameters for ```syscall```s https://blog.rchapman.org/posts/Linux_System_Call_Table_for_x86_64/